# What is the LinkedList equivalent in iOS frameworks?

Tags: java, objective-c, ios, cocoa, list

In java, one can make use of the generic `LinkedList` to improve the efficiency when objects are often added to the front of the list. What is its equivalent in the iOS frameworks?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to understand that in Foundation classes like `NSArray`, etc, **is not what you learned as an array, etc in your beginning programming class.** In particular, it doesn't have the performance characteristics you would normally associate to an array.

On this point, there are many nice blog posts, e.g. one by [Ridiculous Fish](https://web.archive.org/web/20060614135819/http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/) and another by [Cocoa with Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/08/nsarray-or-nsset-nsdictionary-or.html)

So, as everybody else said, just use `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: For large collections, arrays have terrible insert / delete performance

Comment: Yes, but `NSMutableArray` is not an array.

Comment: D'oh! That explains it.

Answer (score 12):

[NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is closest to this. Despite the name, it's closer to a list than an array. However, *"appending to and removing elements from either end take constant time"*, according to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html).

Also, what about this, a third-party implementation: https://github.com/mschettler/NSLinkedList

Comment: +1 `NSArray` has a *ton* of optimizations under-the-hood, and using the built-in solution is always the best option.  Since appending to either end is a constant time operation, the need for an actual linked list is negated, since `NSArray` already has the desired performance characteristics.

Comment: Do you have a source for these appending and removing perfomance characteristics? Ctrl+F doesn't come up with the line you quote in the documentation.

Comment: Ah, sorry - it's from a different page :)

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct equivalent. Writing a linked list yourself is pretty easy, but I doubt that you will gain a lot of performance compared to `NSMutableArray`.

There are a couple of different linked list implementations in the open source [CHDataStructures](https://github.com/davedelong/CHDataStructures).

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableArray is a vector or dynamic array but it is *not* a linkedlist.

Comment: if NSMutableArray is a vector or dynamic array. What would be and equivalent to linked list in objective-c ?